# fetching data from database, but data will repeat twice

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.attendance_Date, E.loc_id, E.Student, E.RoomNo, E.music_id, E.lesson_id, E.lesson_code, E.grade_id, E.grade_Cost, E.InstructorFinancePercent, E.Instructor, E.event_status, E.grade_id 
FROM events E 
left join tbl_teacher_attendance A ON E.Instructor = A.teacher_Name
```

This is my query for fetching data, but it will repeat data twice for all record.Can anyone explain me why this is happend and solution for preventing this repetation.

[image]

Comment: I cannot see any repeating row. At least one column value is different than the other(s).

Comment: I do NOT se duplicates - each row is unique.

Comment: how can i make distinct column attendance_Date??

Comment: No way. Or you must define what student must be returned and what student(s) must be ignored.

Comment: ok,, i will try this.

Comment: yes will repeat if one of them has two records with the same foreign key, you will have to correct it through a loop if you did not get please let me know what data you are getting and what you expect

Answer (score 0):

Use Group By to eliminate repeated data. Something like this

```
SELECT A.attendance_Date, E.loc_id, E.Student, E.RoomNo, E.music_id, E.lesson_id, E.lesson_code, E.grade_id, E.grade_Cost, E.InstructorFinancePercent, E.Instructor, E.event_status, E.grade_id 
FROM events E 
left join tbl_teacher_attendance A ON E.Instructor = A.teacher_Name GROUP BY A.attendance_Date
```

Comment: No. In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate